# Getting elements from MongoDB in NodeJS and adding to list/array to be processed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

So I'm working on a full stack project that needs to retrieve stock data from mongodb and run algorithms on certain information, so here I have an example of the JSON object that mongodb stores, so here is an example of the object in mongodb

```
[{
  _id: 5e11d67abf05f3d00d56b801,
  LUNA: {
    'Previous Close': '7.38',
    Open: '7.26',
    Bid: '7.15 x 800',
    Ask: '7.43 x 800',
    "Day's Range": '7.17 - 7.36',
    '52 Week Range': '3.03 - 7.83',
    Volume: '94,415',
    'Avg Volume': '216,919',
    'Market Cap': '217M',
    'Beta (5Y Monthly)': '0.77',
    'PE Ratio (TTM)': '59.34',
    'EPS (TTM)': 0.121,
    'Earnings Date': '2019-11-05',
    'Forward Dividend & Yield': 'N/A (N/A)',
    'Ex-Dividend Date': 'N/A',
    '1y Target Est': 7.65,
    ticker: 'LUNA'
  }
}]
```

My question is how do I store only certain elements of all the objects in an array or list, such as only price and P/E, and because it's in a string notation I also have to deal with conversion as well. I'm new to the stack so go easy on me.

So i.e I'de like an 2d array/list with Price/PE or a array/list with price so that I can run algos on it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output array you are trying to get?

Comment: I think you have to _project_ (as in projection) only the fields you want from the document. The `find()` method returns a cursor and the cursor can be converted to an array. See these: [Return Specific Fields in Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/index.html#return-specific-fields-in-embedded-documents) and [Cursor to Array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#cursor.toArray).

Answer (score 0):

My buddy solved it - because it's a JSON object, I just accessed the object as follows - result[0].ARVN.Open

Now I'm just creating a data structure to store the info in, probably will use a hashmap.